# Template Parse Errors

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, angular-material2

I have imported all the required modules and still facing this error.

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-select'.
1. If 'md-select' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then 
verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-select' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to 
the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' 
of this component.
```

Comment: You need to add `FormsModule` to `imports: [...]` of the module uses `md-select`

Comment: make sure that `FormsModule` & `CommonModule` are added in your `AppModule` imports

Comment: all the modules are imported

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have included **`BrowserModule,MaterialModule,FormsModule`**

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
})
```

Comment: problem is i have different module for routing in each component so every module i had declared in main app.module.ts and so it was throwing parse errors i had to declare all the modules and components to a particular routing module then it started working fine

Comment: @Sajeetharan You **should not** import `MaterialModule` as it is deprecated from beta 3 and to import the modules you need for your app to work.